# I use isolate.spawnUri() in flutter and caused a fatal error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

this is my cod:

```
  void callTask()async{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse('package:flutter_bedrock/base_framework/utils/isolate/factory/proxy_isolate.dart');

    final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
    Isolate isolate = await Isolate.spawnUri(uri,
        [], receivePort.sendPort);
    SendPort childPort;
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      print('msg from proxy $message');
      if(message[0] == kSendPortKey){
        childPort = message[1];
        childPort.send([kTaskKey,'test']);
      }
    });



  }
```

I invoke callTask() at flutter, and log this :

```
E/flutter (14779): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(864)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (14779): error: native function 'Window_setNeedsReportTimings' (2 arguments) cannot be found
E/flutter (14779): #0      Window.onReportTimings= (dart:ui/window.dart:964:29)
E/flutter (14779): #1      SchedulerBinding.addTimingsCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:234:14)
E/flutter (14779): #2      SchedulerBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:210:7)
E/flutter (14779): #3      PaintingBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:21:11)
E/flutter (14779): #4      SemanticsBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/semantics/binding.dart:22:11)
E/flutter (14779): #5      RendererBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:30:11)
E/flutter (14779): #6      WidgetsBinding.initInstances (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:255:11)
E/flutter (14779): #7      new BindingBase (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:57:5)
E/flutter (14779): #8      new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (14779): #9      new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (14779): #10     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (14779): #11     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (14779): #12     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (14779): #13     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (14779): #14     new _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (14779): #15     new WidgetsFlutterBinding (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
E/flutter (14779): #16     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1203:7)
E/flutter (14779): #17     main (package:flutter_bedrock/main.dart:24:25)
E/flutter (14779): #18     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
E/flutter (14779): #19     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

in main isolate :

```
void main(){
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   IsolatePoolProxy.getInstance().callTask();
}


import 'dart:isolate';


const int kSendPortKey = 6633;

const int kTaskKey = 8844; 
///
const String kMethodName = 'kMethodName';
const String kNameArgs = 'kNameArgs';

class IsolatePoolProxy{

  IsolatePoolProxy._();

  static IsolatePoolProxy _instance;

  factory IsolatePoolProxy() => getInstance();

  static IsolatePoolProxy getInstance(){
    if(_instance == null){
      _instance = IsolatePoolProxy._();
    }
    return _instance;
  }


  void callTask()async{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse('package:flutter_bedrock/base_framework/utils/isolate/factory/proxy_isolate.dart');

    final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
    Isolate isolate = await Isolate.spawnUri(uri,
        [], receivePort.sendPort);
    SendPort childPort;
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      print('msg from proxy $message');
      if(message[0] == kSendPortKey){
        childPort = message[1];
        childPort.send([kTaskKey,'test']);
      }
    });



  }


}
```

in child isolate at proxy_isolate.dart file :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';


const int kSendPortKey = 6633;

const int kTaskKey = 8844; 

///
const String kMethodName = 'kMethodName';
const String kNameArgs = 'kNameArgs';



final List<String> orders = [];

void main( args,SendPort mainPort)async{

  ///connect with main isolate
  final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  final SendPort sendPort = receivePort.sendPort;
  receivePort.listen((message) {
    print('msg from main  $message');
    if(message[0] == kTaskKey){
      orders.add(message[1]);
    }

  });

  mainPort.send([kSendPortKey,sendPort]);

}
```

E/flutter (14779): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(864)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (14779): error: native function 'Window_setNeedsReportTimings' (2 arguments) cannot be found

Comment: Please do not paste code as pictures. apart from screenreader, that cannot read pictures, and Google, that cannot index pictures for searches for code, even we human readers have no way of copying the code into our IDEs. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Where is your main method? Please post a [mcve]. This is the last time I post you this link. Please read it. It is a very short list of direct instructions. If you cannot follow them, I cannot help.

Comment: @nvoigt
haha ,sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `dart:ui` in isolates.

See [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55291) on the flutter github.

There does not seem to be a workaround. You cannot do it that way, find another way to do what you want to do.

Comment: thanks reply ,and i checked my code, there is no dart:ui,  i'm not even import it.

Comment: proxy_isolate.dart have a child isolate in it,and didn't import dart:ui. just dart:async.

Comment: sorry i will delete pic

Comment: i add my two part of code. and there are in different file.

Comment: is isolate.spawnUri()  can only use in pure dart project?

Comment: i searched in github issue of flutter,  and found some anwser is  isolate.spawnUri() not support in flutter.    if wanna use isolate, call Isolate.spawn().

Answer (score 0):

don's use spawnUri in flutter.